# How do I use TFS to autobuild a non default configuration

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

We have a large code base with various labels which need autobuilding.
We are using TFS 2012 Express and VS 2010

Our code is build by a batch file so I have created a dummy solution which the autobuild builds, the build instructions for this solution just run the batch file.

I had the idea of using different configurations in this solution to build different labels.

So, as well as debug and release configurations I added one called LABEL which calls a different batch file and added a new automatic build in TFS which calls this solution with the 'label' configuration in the box Required - Configurations to build.

However, when I try to run it it fails claiming that the 'label' configuration does not exist.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Extra:
It seems to work if I use the Release configuration to call one batch file and the Debug one to call another but it still cannot find user created configurations?

Answer (score -1):

If presume "Autobuild" means "build via TFS build definition".

If by "label" you mean a source control label, then when queuing a build, you can set its "Get Version" parameter to a label - for example, for the label `MyLabel` use `LMyLabel`.

If by "label" you mean some definition internal to the batch-file build, then you can pass it via an MSBuild property: Define it in the build definition by adding `"/p:label=mylabel"` to "MSBuild parameters". Then, where the solution calls your batch, you can use `$(label)` to get the value from the build definition.

Also, instead of this hacky .sln, you could modify the build template to call your batch file directly, and have a parameter which you set in the build definition, and the template passes it to the batch file.

Comment: How do you set the build template to directly call the batch file? I tried that but it only seemed to know about Visual Studio project files?

Comment: You need to edit the build template - Usually called `DefaultTemplate.xaml`. It's more involved than just creating build definitions, so I guess you should try to stick with what you have now...

Comment: Okay, I have already tried what you mention above but my build cannot find my user defined configuration. Is there anything else I need to do?